# Remove large MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have an 80GB MySQL database on a Ubuntu server I would like to delete (it is no longer needed).  However, if I try to drop it from the CLI, Webmin, MySQL Workbench, etc... I get an error message saying database connection dropped before it is actually dropped.  Is there a way to manually remove it from the system tables so I can reclaim the disk space?

Comment: [Check this out](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35959/error-when-dropping-innodb-database?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) it seems to be related.

Comment: Although related, that doesn't tell me how to get rid of the database completely.  I was able to take chunks of the records out (it has a single table left) but now I'm stuck in recovery mode only :(